# What is the format of resumes from conferences/fairs?

Tags: management, recruitment, recruiting

I wanted to know if conferences and career fairs gave out resumes in zipfiles? It would make processing ALOT easier. What is the format?

We can't afford an ATS just yet so I wanted to know because I dont want to scan resumes one by one so I can have lots of people view them.

background: I work in silicon valley for a small tech startup.

Comment: Is this the same as your last [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/105247/what-to-do-with-resumes-from-conferences-fairs-etc)?

Comment: Are you the entire team doing the hiring and attending the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the format?

It would be guessing if we told you what format is the one they give.

This strongly depends on the conference or fair; some may give zip files, some may give paper, and some may give both (I doubt they give none). If you want to know if a *specific* conference offers their resumes on zip files **I suggest you contact them to ask for this detail** to get a better answer.

> We can't afford an ATS just yet so I wanted to know because I dont want to scan resumes one by one so I can have lots of people view them.

As I see this you have two scenarios:

1. **They don't give zip files.** For which you will have to *prepare yourself to be able to scan any resume you get on paper* (hopefully other conferences do give zips).
2. **They give zip files**. In which case no problem, as you can easily share them with others for consideration.

I suggest you give both of them a thought so you can better prepare yourself for this task in case you do have a lot of papers to scan. Be sure to inform about this to whomever you consider necessary so they are aware of this.

Comment: Thank you for the only valuable response! Very useful, thank you! Do you normally manually go through all the resumes in the stack (zipfile or paper) ? And do you get them before or after the conference usually? (stress on usually, I know they can all differ)

Comment: And sorry for the post, I'm just a bit nervous for the new job. Shall I delete the question and post following the guidelines?

Comment: @iphone42recruithr usually reading resumes is indeed a task of going manually through all of them and cross checking the candidates. Don't worry, just try to read a bit more about the site the next time you post. No need to necessarily delete your post, perhaps edit for improvements if you wish. Hope you do good on your job, good luck